# How to remove circular reference from a REST API response?

Tags: java, spring, rest

When returning a json that has a child object that refereces the parent, there's a circular reference problem causing an error because the loop never ends.

For instance, let's say I have a relationship between User entity and a Roles entity and I want to return them in a json.

GetUsers

```
{
    "userId": "1",
    "userName": "USER1",
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleId": "5",
            "role": "ADMIN",
            "users": [
                    {   /*CIRCULAR REFERENCE HERE*/
                        "userId": "1",
                        "userName": "USER1",
                        "roles": [...]
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "2",
                        "userName": "USER2",
                        "roles": [...]
                    }
                ]

        },
        {
            "roleId": "6",
            "role": "MANAGER"
            "users": [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

GetRoles

```
{
    "roleId": "5",
    "role": "ADMIN",
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "userName": "USER1",
            "roles": [
                    {   /*CIRCULAR REFERENCE HERE*/
                        "roleId": "5",
                        "role": "ADMIN",
                        "users": [...]
                    },
                    {
                        "roleId": "6",
                        "role": "MANAGER",
                        "users": [...]
                    }
                ]

        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "userName": "USER2",
            "roles": [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the best approach to solve this issue?

I know I could use @JsonIgnore for Roles attribute in the Users entity and for Users attribute in Roles entity.

But then GetUsers would not return roles data and GetRoles would not return users data.

I'd like a solution that returns those, but not the circular reference. Like this:

GetUsers

```
{
    "userId": "1",
    "userName": "USER1",
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleId": "5",
            "role": "ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "roleId": "6",
            "role": "MANAGER"
        }
    ]
}
```

GetRoles

```
{
    "roleId": "5",
    "role": "ADMIN",
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "userName": "USER1"
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "userName": "USER2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use a custom serializer. [Here's an example.](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

Comment: @Christopher Schneider I updated the question title to make it more clear. I'm looking for a solution for HTTP Get Response for the Rest API.

Comment: As usual with this kind of question, you should not serialize/deserialize your entities. Use DTOs for this purpose.

Comment: I do have DTOs. I didn't put in the question for simplicity. You can consider that the two classes I mentioned in the question are DTOs. What would be the solution in that case?

Comment: And btw I had updated the question title to remove the word serialization.

Comment: @jkfe That doesn't change that the solution is to use a custom serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to return references to identifiers rather than the full object:

```json
{
  "users": [ 
     {
        "userId": "1",
        "userName": "USER1",
        "roleIds": ["5, 6"]
     },
     {
         "userId": "2",
         "userName": "USER2",
         "roleIds": ["5, 6"]
     }
  ],

  "roles": [
     {
        "roleId": "5",
        "role": "ADMIN",
        "userIds": ["1", "2"]
     },
     {
        "roleId": "6",
        "role": "MANAGER",
        "userIds": ["1", "2"]
     }
  ]
}
```

You can also use a more generic approach as described in [Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html):

```json
{
    "usersById": {
        "1": {
            userName: "USER1",
            roles: [
              { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "5"] },
              { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "6"] }
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            userName: "USER2",
            roles: [
              { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "5"] },
              { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "6"] }
            ]
        }
    },
    "rolesById": {
        "5": {
           role: "ADMIN",
           users: [
              { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "1"] },
              { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "2"] }
           ]
        },
        "6": {
           role: "MANAGER",
           users: [
              { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "1"] },
              { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "2"] }
           ]
        }

    },
    "users": [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "1"] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["usersById", "2"] }       
    ],
    "roles": [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "5"] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["rolesById", "6"] }       
    ]
}
```

## Edit

### GetUsers

Just craft DTOs that don't have the circular references:

```json
{
    "userId": "1",
    "userName": "USER1",
    "roles": [
        {
            "roleId": "5",
            "role": "ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "roleId": "6",
            "role": "MANAGER"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I need this information in the response: ```{"roleId": "5", "role": "ADMIN"}``` for GetUsers and vice-versa for GetRoles. In reality there are more fields than just those and need all of them in the response. Just don't need the part that makes the circular reference. Like in the two last blocks of code in my question.

Comment: @jkfe - There are a number of ways to approach this. I've added another to my answer.

Comment: Right. DTOs without the circular reference is a good solution. Setting to null also worked. Answer accepted. Although in this second case, would need to do that every time it needs to be called which is not good. So DTO is better. The only thing is that more than one Response DTO would need to be created, one for each situation.